# Why the applicationIconBadgeNumber is not getting deleted with appliccation ? Where it stored actually?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I deleted my application from iPad. And try to relaunch again. But now it displays old applicationIconBadgeNumber at very first launch. Any one know where this value is stored and why it's not deleted with application. How can we handle this scenario.