# ApplicationIconBadgeNumber is not getting reset on reinstallation of my ipad app.

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm setting my applicationIconBadgeNumber using this code:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:theIntToDisplay];`

The problem is that when I delete the app from an iPad and reinstall it, the app icon still shows the previous badge number. Is this default iOS behavior or can we reset it?

I found one similar question on at [Why the applicationIconBadgeNumber is not getting deleted with appliccation ? Where it stored actually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034445/why-the-applicationiconbadgenumber-is-not-getting-deleted-with-appliccation-wh), but it didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an expected behavior, the badge number remains for a short period after uninstall e.g for the case of an immediate re-install.

Of course you can nullify badge number after every launching the application in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method but I think it is not the case because you want badge number not to be shown right after you install app and not yet launch it. In such a case just wait after removing the application and the badge numbers cache will be cleared by iOS and then install the app again. Unfortunately without jailbreaking the device there is no way to manage badge numbers behavior manually

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. 
so how long I should wait. Is this time specified any where. I mean Did apple talk about It.

Comment: @RamanujSingh I can't say you the exact time.When I encounted with such an issue it takes from 30 minutes to several hours.It is all implenentation detail things.Because managing app icons and badges is iOS low level underhood. There are tweaks from Cydia like this http://www.imore.com/clear-icon-badges-badgeclear-jailbreak which use jailbreak to manage badge icons and clear it.So you can use it.Also you can write to Apple tech support and ask them for details but I think there is no need because as i said it is well expcted behavior - i write to their tech support on similar issue

Comment: @RamanujSingh Also look here. I found discussion of this problem on Apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4960850 it is related to app's cache as i said

Answer (score 4):

In your app delegate under:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

Insert:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```